# What is and how to solve the warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=] when printing it out

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int array[5]={10,20,30,40,50};
  int *p;
  p=array;
  printf("%p\n", array);
  printf("%p\n", p);
  printf("%p\n", &array[0]);
  printf("%p\n", &p[0]);
  printf("%p\n", &(*array));

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code with GCC and printing the values of the addresses out with `%p` gives the following warnings:

> ````
> 01.c: In function ‘main’:
> 01.c:7:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]    printf("%p\n", array);
>            ~^     ~~~~~
>            %ls
> 01.c:8:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]    printf("%p\n", p);
>            ~^     ~
>            %ls
> 01.c:9:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]    printf("%p\n", &array[0]);
>            ~^     ~~~~~~~~~
>            %ls
> 01.c:10:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]    printf("%p\n", &p[0]);
>            ~^     ~~~~~
>            %ls
> 01.c:11:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]    printf("%p\n",
> &(*array));
>            ~^     ~~~~~~~~~
>            %ls ```
> ````

How can I solve them and why are they happening? Also, what is `%ls`?

Comment: `"%ls"` comes up from the compiler thinking that maybe your are attempting a wide character string printing.

Comment: This is perhaps a case in which OP should ignore downvotes. Many examples on SO of questions and answers using `%p` incorrectly without the cast, and many examples of questions and answers ignoring warnings. Kudos to you @DuarteArribas for taking warnings seriously.

Comment: @exnihilo Yeah, I try to turn on all the warnings I can, so my code's the best possible

Comment: A useful model is to think that `int *`, `float *`, `struct foo *`, and many others can reference different memory locations with different pointer sizes and encoding - yet `void *` can represent all.  Thus say sending a 2-byte `int *` to `printf()` and `printf()` expecting a 4-byte `void *` is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object pointer of any type may be implicitly converted to a `void *` without a cast, and the reverse is also true.

However, the `%p` format specifier to `printf` explicitly expects a `void *` argument, and because `printf` is a variadic function that implicit conversion won't happen.

This is one of the rare cases when an explicit cast to `void *` is required:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)array);
printf("%p\n", (void *)p);
printf("%p\n", (void *)&array[0]);
printf("%p\n", (void *)&p[0]);
printf("%p\n", (void *)&(*array));
```

On most implementations you're likely to come in contact with, objects pointers and `void *` have the same representation.  However that is not necessarily true in general, and failing to cast can cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on systems where this is not true.

In contrast, calling the function `foo` below does not require a cast:

```
void foo(void *p)
{
    printf("p=%p\n", p);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    foo(&x);
}
```

Because the type of the parameter is known at compile time.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, so best practice, every time I use `%p` I should cast it to `void *`?

Comment: @DuarteArribas Correct, always cast to `void *` when using `%p` (if it's not already that type).

Answer (score 0):

it needs another type of pointer. You need to cast it to `void *`

`printf("%p\n", array);` => `printf("%p\n", (void *)array);`

Comment: I explained: `%p` requires `void *`

Comment: @P__J__ -- "_You need to cast it to `void *`_" isn't really an explanation; that the Standard requires it might be a better start. [p    The argument shall be a pointer to void.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8)